# How to get Sum of Gallon,milliliters and liters in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I will trying to get sum of these:

5 liter/s

3 liter/s

5 mL/s

4 gallons

the final answer is 6.1240040 gallon/s

and now this is it ! but i don't know on  how to determine its unit.

```
      select SUM(CASE WHEN unit = 'liter/s' AND Quantity >= 3.785 then   
             Quantity / 3.785  
             WHEN unit = 'liter/s' AND Quantity < 3.785 then Quantity / 1000 
             WHEN unit = 'gallon/s' THEN Quantity 
             WHEN Unit = 'mL/s' AND Quantity <= 1000 THEN Quantity / 1000  
             END) AS 'RESULT'  from raw
```

Please help me. I need to pass this project.

Comment: Choose a unit as result and change all those values into that unit and then add them up together.

Comment: select CONCAT(SUM(Quantity * Case when Unit = 'mL/s' then 1 when Unit = 'liter/s' then 1000 when Unit='gallon/s' then 3.785)) as 'result' from product

Comment: That is my code right now but the result is wrong.

Comment: Then [edit] your question and add your current code into your question. Add what you get right now and what you expected to get. (See: [ask])

Comment: Do you have them unit and quantity as separate columns or a single one?

Comment: It's much better to store values in a common unit and handle the conversion for presentation in your application. That is, pick something like mL/s and convert everything to that, then back again. You can then get gallons per hour, acre-feet per day, anything you want with the right conversion factors. Storing in mixed units is how [colossal mistakes happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter).

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONCAT(SUM(Quantity * Case when Unit like '%mL/s%' then 1 when Unit like '%liter/s%' then 1000 when Unit like '%gallon/s%' then 3.785)) as 'result' from product
```

Use the above query which should work for the data you have given

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUM((Case when Unit = 'mL/s' then  1 
 when Unit =    liter/s' then 1000 
 when Unit='gallon/s'  then 3785.41 end case)*Quantity) 
as 'result' from product
```

You don't need concat their

explanation
case statement will return the  required units in ml and then it will be multiplied by Quantity 
then you will get sum of all values 
you will get final result in ml

Comment: Ok your answer is correct but how to calculate if the result is greater than or equal to  3.785 then the answer is divide by 3.785?

Comment: can you please check and let me know